# Titanium Studio - Adding SDK's later(Android first project)

Tags: android, ios, titanium, appcelerator

I'm doing a minor crossplatform application, and have chosen Titanium studio after researching whats out there.

Can anyone tell me if it's possible to first develop a prototype for Android, and when content then go on to IOS, or if both strictly have to be enable from the get go?

For the IOS specific parts, I'm forced to work on a remote machine, which is why I would prefer to have as much finished as possible before that.

Hope that makes sense, and someone can help me out! Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to make App for Android only and later make required changes for iOS.

Comment: Thank you. I'll just hold out a bit, to see if someone would like to explain a bit further. Does it simply let you compile, when the IOS SDK is configured? Thanks again.

Comment: Could you perhaps elaborate?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. You just need to set the android sdk path and test it on android emulator or android device. you need not to worry about ios devices.